# how to create an interlaced rows images with python and openCv

Tags: image, opencv, python-2.7, numpy

I have two images with the same size. I would like to create a new interlaced image where the odd rows belong to one image and the even rows to the other image.
Like a 3d image.
I am trying to do that with python and openCv and numpy!
Reading the two images and with a loop i try to write the values in the odd and even rows.

I don't know if this is the best way to do that. Do you have some tips?

Here the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def main():
    print 'loading images...'
    imgL= cv2.imread('sx2.jpg')
    imgR= cv2.imread('dx2.jpg')
    h, w = imgL.shape[:2]
    print h, w
    cv2.imshow(interlace(imgL, imgR, h, w))
    cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def interlace(imgL, imgR, h, w):
    inter= np.empty((h, w, 3),int)
    for z in range (0,3):
        for i in range(h-1):
            for j in range(w-1):
                if j % 2 == 0:
                    inter[i][j][z]= imgL[i][j][z]
                else:
                    inter[i][j][z]= imgR[i][j][z]


    b=np.float32(inter) / 255.0
    return b


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Do you want to know a faster way? or a more elegant way? or just to know if this is the right way you are doing it? Your question asks if this is the "best" way to do it, can you be more specific on the word "best" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be much faster than your approach:

```
def interlace(imgL, imgR, h, w):
    inter = np.empty((h, w, 3), imgL.dtype)
    inter[:h:2, :w, :] = imgL[:h:2, :w, :]
    inter[1:h:2, :w, :] = imgL[1:h:2, :w, :]
    return inter.astype(np.float32) / 255
```

As general rules, try to avoid explicit for loops iterating over numpy arrays, its almost always faster to do a vectorized approach. And don't index numpy arrays as `a[i][j][k]`, use `a[i, j, k]` instead, it is faster and more powerful.

Comment: Thanks for the advises! your code seems to work and it is faster!
I have to just understand better how this vectorized approach works. Like why you wrote '[:h:2, :w, :]' and '[1:h:2, :w, :]' :)

Comment: The [numpy reference](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) has a very detailed explanation on how indexing works. The `start:stop:step` notation I used above is explained in the Basic Slicing section.